# How do you execute directive code after rendering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to build a directive that runs after a nested `ng-repeat` has completed rendering. Here's what I've tried [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/lolson/ZTMex/):

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul my-directive>
        <li ng-repeat="animal in animals">{{animal}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
angular.module("MyApp", [])
    .directive("myDirective", function () {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            alert(element.find("li").length); // 0
        };
    });

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.animals = ["Dog", "Cat", "Elephant"];
}
```

The linking function in my custom directive runs before all of the `<li>` elements have been rendered (and `0` is alerted). How do I run code after the `ng-repeat` has completed rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the directive inside ng-repeat, http://jsfiddle.net/ZTMex/3/

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="animal in animals" my-directive>{{animal}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13472605/1986890 which is related to your question.