# Execute jquery function after ng-repeat has finished

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, height, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table where the rows are repeated with `ng-repeat`. The height of each row is dynamically set based on the content. I need to get this specific height for each row, but when i try to get with a directive the height attribute has always the same value. It seems to me, that the jquery `height()` function inside my directive is fired, before the specific content is inserted in each row. Is there a way to execute the `height()` function in my directive after `ng-repeat` has finished?

Comment: i'm assuming that ng-repeat doesn't act before the .ready() takes action and you've tested it? I just want to make sure, don't take it personal or anything

Comment: You can try the $timeout service in AngularJS. It's very difficult to determine exactly when rendering is finished.

Comment: you can just do the height() call in a directive after ng-repeat has called its $last element check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event