# access to ng-included DOM nodes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My first experiment with angular.js.

I've a few columns, each of them includes some template:

```
<div class="col-md-5 js-column" ng-repeat="orm in orms" repeat-done="equalHeight">
    <h2>{{ orm.name }}</h2>
    <ng-include src="'/inc/_compiled/'+orm.id+'.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Each included template contains the same elements as other templates, but they've different height. Example element:

```
<pre data-task="model" class="task-model">
from django.db import models
class Teacher(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

</pre>
```

The thing I want to achieve is to set equal height for specific element in all the columns. That means all `pre.task-model` will have the same height.

I've created some directive and the idea was to trigger it after `ngRepeat` loop is finished (`scope.$last`). But when I try to access the included nodes via jQuery/DOM selectors, I get nothing. I know each template is available in `element` variable, but I need to get also the other columns.

```
var ormApp = angular
    .module('ormApp', [])
    .directive('repeatDone', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) {
                $('.js-column pre.task-model'); //<- got nothing
            }
        };
    })
```

Comment: My guess is that the directive is triggered before the DOM is updated. What happens if you put your jQuery selector in a setTimeout function?

Comment: Can't you use CSS for that?

Comment: @JonasHartmann I would like to, but I can't imagine how to do it via css.

Comment: @Nathan setting timeout helped (even if it's not nice solution), thanks.

Comment: pre.task-model { height: 200px; } // Try that out, but maybe I didn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @JonasHartmann there's a plenty of these `pre` elements (pre.task-foo, pre.task-bar...) and I don't know height of their content so setting it to some specific number wouldn't work.

Comment: Following the idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13472605/1981709 You could try to add your directive to each element inside the template, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using `$timeout` solves the problem.
But why ?

The issue here is that several operations involved in the process, such as creating a new element (by `ngRepeat`), fetching the template (by `ngInclude`) using `$http.get()` (even if it comes from the `$templateCache`), resolving the promises returned etc, are asynchronously and are handled using `$evalAsync()`, which means that they are going to "happen" when everything else currently on Angular's async queue is processed.

Since there are several levels of nested `$evalAsync`s (in this particular case 7), you can achieve what you want by iteratively calling `$evalAsync()` until the async operations required for fetching and lining the template are completed.

This is of course not a robust (or recommended) way to solve the problem, it is just meant to explain what is going on.
Using `$timeout` puts the operation in the browser's event queue, so the command will be processed after Angular's current $digest loop is completed (i.e. after all tasks on Angular's async queue have been processed and all taks added to the queue by those async taks etc).
(Another side-effect here is that, since the rendering engine's "render" command is already on the browser event queue, using `$timeout` will execute the command after the next DOM rendering has taken place. This has no relevance for this particular case, but might be important in other situations.)

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/5aLkZ/)** illustrating both aproaches (open the DevTools console).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example. It looks like Angular is much more complex than I've thought.