# AngularJS event for when model binding or ng-repeat is complete?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

We have a large model and it takes a couple seconds for ng-repeat to bind all the items in the model to the form. We would like to show a spinner while it this is happening. Is there some event that fires when binding is complete so we know when to hide the spinner?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event is this what you're looking for? I didn't flag as duplicate because I don't know enough about Angular to make that call. Hope this helps you though.

Comment: I'm no angularjs expert, but the binding should be a syncronous operation. Show the spinner before the call, hide it after: no need to use callbacks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GzzTW4?p=preview

Use `ng-show` on the spinner If you are using 1.2 use `ng-if`

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-show="complete">Complete={{complete}}</div>
    <div class="thing" ng-repeat="thing in things" my-post-repeat-directive>
       thing {{thing}}
   </div>
</div>
```

In your directive use $last to determine if rendering is done and then change the variable that you have the ng-show/ngif defined on.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.complete=false;  
  $scope.doComplete = function() {
      $scope.complete = true;
  }

  $scope.things = [
    'A', 'B', 'C'
  ];
}

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myPostRepeatDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last) {
        scope.$eval('doComplete()');
      }
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can watch for `$last` item compile/link function, and fire a custom event to the scope

Answer (score 2):

In that kind of situations, I use the [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout) service mixed with the [$viewContentLoaded](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events) event fired by angular ui router (if you use ui router) :

about $timeout :

> This service is just a simple decorator for $timeout service that  adds a "flush" and "verifyNoPendingTasks" methods.

about $viewContentLoaded

> fired once the view is loaded, after the DOM is rendered. The '$scope' of the view emits the event.

My personal usecase is for a paymentForm to dynamically generate its hidden inputs (using HTML data computed serverside that I insert through  ng-bind-html) and submit to the payment Gateway :

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { 
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.paymentForm.submit();
    });
});
```

FYI in the above code example,  .submit() is a function from a custom directive used with the form in order to be able to autosubmit the form.

Julien

Answer (score -1):

For this I normally create a spinner div in your view with an ng-show="submitting". Then when the data is loaded, you set the $scope.submitting to 'false' show the spinner is hidden.

```
<!-- In your HTML -->
<div class="spinner" ng-show="submitting">
<div ng-repeat="p in people">
   {{p.name}}
</div>

//In Javascript
$scope.submitting = true;
$scope.load_data = function(){
    $http.get('/api/route')
        .then(function(success){
            $scope.submitting = false;
        },function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I think the question is not so much about showing the spinner during a service call but during the processing of a large ng-repeat array.