# Manipulate template after compilation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angular-directive

I have a simple template that uses ng-repeat:

template.html

```
<div id='tmpl'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.desc }}</li> 
 </ul>
</div>
```

Inside my directive, I am compiling that template with a custom scope. and then that template is added to the page:

```
var element = $('#my-div');
var compiledTemplate = $compile(scope.template)(customScope);
element.before(compiledTemplate);
$('#tmpl').show();
```

This works well, however the issue is that after calling the show(), I am trying to access the templates innerHeight(), but at that time ng-repeat inside the template isn't executed yet and I'm getting the value before the elements are rendered.

```
   $('#tmpl').innerHeight(); // returns value before ng-repeat is finished
```

So, is there a secure way to do DOM manipulation of the compiled element, after ng-repeat finish processing elements?

Comment: Consider making the manipulation after `ng-repeat` finishes. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864007/angularjs-event-for-when-model-binding-or-ng-repeat-is-complete, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a directive and get the 'innerHeight' in the post link phase.
The ng-repeat should already been executed and the correct height should be available.

Alternatively you can use $timeout and run the function after the template has completely rendered.

Comment: Just tried wrapping DOM manipulation inside the $timeout, and this seems to work, thanks.