# $scope.$watch for check if ng-repeat finished rendering

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the snippet i have used for watch $last for an ng-repeat

```
$scope.$watch('$last',function(){
    console.log('dgfdf');
    if($scope.loading>0){
        $scope.loading--;
    }
});
```

But it does't fires at all.

NB:Is their a way to show an animating view when ng-repeat rendering it's content?

Comment: This should work if `$scope` is the scope that `ngRepeat` makes. `ngRepeat` creates a scope for each element it creates and sets `$last` for the last one. So, if you have a watch on an outer scope, it will indeed not fire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-repeat finish event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event)