# Defer process after data retrieval and display

Tags: angularjs

Hi I  have a factory that GETs data from a backend. This data is then processed with a controller (as seen below) and injected in the web page with ng-repeat. Due to asynchronous nature of the system, I have troubles when I try to manipulate window. For example I need to use window.scrollTo function but only AFTER data was completely processed and displayed on screen with ng-repeat.

As you can see here, I tried to use a promise early in the controller. But it doesn't work: window.scrollTo is always processed before data has finished being processed on screen. I guess what I need is a way to actually force the data process to be completed and only then process the window.scrollTo function but I don't see how.

```
    .controller('myCtrl',
    function ($scope, prosFactory, fieldValues, $q ) {
        $scope.listpros = function() {
            prosFactory.getPros()
                .success(function(data, status) {
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    defer.promise
                        .then(function () {
                          $scope.prosItems = data;  // pass data to ng repeat first                           
                            })
                        .then(function () {
                            $window.scrollTo(0, 66); // then scroll 
                          });
                    defer.resolve();   
                }).error(function(data, status) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            );
        };
```

I tried with a 2000 timeout on scrollTo function, but due to variation in internet speed, it sometimes delay the scroll to much, or sometime isn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A promise won't help much in this case, because it is not connected to the `ng-repeat` process by any means. However you could use a custom directive to `$emit` an event when the last item got processed. Your controller could listen to that specific event and react to it according to your needs.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13472605/1326146) shows you how to achieve this, it even comes with a Plunker.

**EDIT: General approach to control DOM creation**

Within the AngularJS world, DOM elements are controlled and, in this case supervised, by directives. The answer I linked to above extends the behavior of a `ng-repeat` directive, but you could do the same for possibly any DOM element. A directive `creation-emitter` could look something like this:

```
myModule.directive('creationEmitter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    scope.$emit('preCompile', iElement)
                },
                post: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    scope.$emit('postCompile', iElement)
                }
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.$emit('link', iElement)
        }
    };
});
```

You could now listen to all those events in a controller that's above the given element in the DOM (for child elements use `$broadcast`).

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with reacting after the data is processed. It looks like he's correctly handling the promise (I assume) returned from the service. 

I think what is happening is that there are missing DOM elements when scrollto is called. He's loading the data into a a model called prosItems and then scrolling to a position on screen. I'm guessing that position is based on ng-repeat completing and inserting the new DOM nodes. What's happening is that it's scrolling to BEFORE the html is inserted in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening. The solution from Lukas did help and I thank him for that: I achieve what I need to when specifically tying the solution to ng repeat. But if someone knows a more general solution with waiting for dom render completion, it would be interesting to read about.

Comment: @Hattan: I wasn't talking about the promise returned by the service, but the one Robert is creating himself. For the general approach: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to chain promises and do intermediate processing.
The immideate callback must return what the next will receive.

I don't see any immediate problems with this approach:

```
prosFactory.getPros()
  .then(processCb)
  .then(doSomethingWithProcessedDataCb)
  .catch(errorCb)
  .finally(scrollWindowCb)
```

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q), it's actually quite good.