# bootstrap-timepicker directive not working inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mT5t5oD9OZop61FaaTJn)

I'm trying to create an arbitrary number of `timepicker`, when hardcoded they work fine but it stops working when I put them into an `ng-repeat`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I believe it is because `$('.bootstrap-timepicker').timepicker();` is running before the repeater elements are rendered. I added a timeout and it works, check out this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/XXguFcnHn5H2RG8EBsON?p=preview). I'm not sure if AngularJS has a watcher to see if all views have been rendered. Something to look into.

Comment: I added a better solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XXguFcnHn5H2RG8EBsON?p=preview) with a better solution.

[Tiago answered AngularJS ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13472605/1134705) with a great directive that will solve your issue without using the `$timeout`

Here is a copy of the directive:

```
app.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
   return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last) {
         $('.bootstrap-timepicker').timepicker();
      }
   };
});
```

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="list in lists" my-repeat-directive>
   {{list.name}}
   <div class="input-append">
      <input type="text" class="bootstrap-timepicker">
      <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
   </div>
</li>
```

This is better because if you repeater requires data from an ajax request than your timeout could have to be altered and cause an ugly user experience.

Tiago's method seems to handle it best, in my opinion, you might also want to give him an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the `ng-init` because solution provided by `Asok` was not working for me. I also didn't want to use `$scope`

**AngularCode**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', MyController);
function MyController($http) {

// your code here...
jd.InitTime = function () {
        $('.bootstrap-timepicker').timepicker();
    };
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-app="MyApp" data-ng-controller="MyController as mc">
    <li ng-repeat="list in mc.lists">
       {{list.name}}
      <div class="input-append">
          <input type="text" class="bootstrap-timepicker" ng-init="mc.InitTime();">
          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
       </div>
    </li>
</div>
```