# trigger when ngRepeat is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In a directive I need to have the width of an element, however this element is created in a `ng-repeat`. So when the code inside my `link` function runs, ngRepeat is not yet executed. I tried to delay things using `$timeout` but that didn't help

JS:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    $timeout(function () {
        var width = $(element.find('li')).width(); // the li elements do not exist
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <my-item>.....</my-item>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I cannot use the `<ol>` element, because the `<my-item>` has styles like margins/paddings.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: check this out, [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)

Answer (score 3):

From [ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event)

```
<ol>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" on-complete>
        <my-item>.....</my-item>
    </li>
</ol>
```

-

```
.directive('onComplete', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element(element).css('color','blue');
    if (scope.$last){
      window.alert("im the last!");
    }
  };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/or5mys?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [scope.$last to generate an event when the last item is done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15208347/169034) or just run the code you need in there.

You might also want to consider your design. Could there be any CSS solution for your problem? If not go ahead.