# looking for a specific element of the page rendered by an ngRepeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to build a date picker, here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="content mCustomScrollbar" style="text-align: left;">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in reservation" >
                <td>
                    <h5><b>{{item.label}}</b></h5>
                </td>
                <td width="120px">

                </td>
                <td >
                    <div ng-show='(item.type=="text")||(item.type=="email")'>

                    </div>
                    <div ng-show='(item.type=="date")' datefield>
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker"> 
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

   </div>
</div>
```

the problem is that the input is located inside ng-repeat iteration, And because of this it isn't working.
I have looked in some places over the web for similar: 
http://blogs.4ward.it/angularjs-call-a-js-function-after-repeat-ends-its-loop/
and also:
[ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event)

how can I call $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); ?
I've tried to do:

```
x.directive("datefield", function(){
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            //alert($("#datepicker").attr('id'));
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    }
}
```

});

the alert is working but the assignment of .datepicker(); doesn't.

Comment: Maybe it is because you have multiple identical ID's? Try with classes. Maybe that resolves it.

Comment: I changed it to class and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `$( "#datepicker" )` in your link function as it is going to target the element with id `datepicker` and you have repeated that id.

Use

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        $(element).datepicker();
}
```