# Angular JS - How to detect that that ng-repeat has finished?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I detect that ng-repeat has finished writing the values into the markup? I have a lot of values and the rendering will take some time.

NG

```
        <ul >

        <li data-ng-repeat="item in values"> 

           {{item.id}}           

        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/angularjs-ng-repeat-finish-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $timeout service.

```
$timeout(function(){
    //done rendering...
 });
```

Pass false as the third argument to prevent another digest cycle if you don't need one:

```
$timeout(function(){
    //done rendering...
 },0,false);
```

You can inject the $timeout service in your controller function:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout){
   ...
});
```

Comment: Where is the $timeout defined, how is it connected to my controller?

Comment: You can inject the service