# Initialize tooltips after view load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How to initialize Bootstrap tooltips after my view is loaded (all ng-repeats etc. are done)?
I have tryed to just include `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` at the bottom of my controller, but it's not initializing tooltips in ngRepeats.

Is there any events which firing on any change of view?

Comment: Is that piece of JS inside an event that fires when the page is finished loading?

Comment: @Jaxo, yep, it is inside `$on.$viewContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) event.

> Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
    console.log('content loaded!')
  });
```

There is no event to notify ng-repeat finish. You can wrap the ng-repeat in a directive and then check for `scope.$last` to be true. In addition you can use $evalAsync to make sure that the callback/function is executed after DOM is constructed.

```
if (scope.$last) {
   scope.$evalAsync(attr.someCallback);
}
```

[ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event)

[Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)

[fiddle ($evalAsync)](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/W8nhv/)

Comment: I have already tryed `$viewContentLoaded` but with no result. It's loaded tooltips in static content, but not in the ngRepeats.