# Initialize bootstrap tooltips after angularJS View has updated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I created an simple AngularJS application, the problem is, that whenever my view will automatically be updated due to changes in the model (which are not shown in the example below), the tooltip doesn't look like an bootstrap tooltip anymore.

I found this answer [satckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591659/initialize-tooltips-after-view-load) but I don't know how to apply this solution. Maybe someone can show me the approach from the provided link at MWE below.

```
<div class="container" ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <h3>Data from Scope: {{data}}</h3>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
     <button type="button" ng-click="refresh()">refresh data</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
  app.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data= 123;
    $scope.refresh = function () {
        $scope.data= Math.random();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your app name is different in html and JS? Also are you going to use router in your project?

Comment: Are you using AngularStrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this dynamic working code.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','[data-toggle="tooltip"]',function(){
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});
```

Idea is when ever you hover your mouse on the elements which has `[data-toggle="tooltip"]` attribute set on them, the tooltip is shown. This works for all the elements (static and dynamic)

Comment: That works thank you, but how do I have to modify the button element to avoid popping up 2 times the tooltip?

Comment: does this solution brings it up two times?? you need to remove your code where you apply the tooltip on document ready.. only this above code is sufficient. if you still have issues then try this `$(this).tooltip('destroy')`. destroy the tooltip and then again apply it..

Comment: @d4rty if this solution fixed your issue please mark it as answer.

Comment: Now everything works, I first put your code inside `$(document).ready(...`. Thank you!

Comment: @d4rty glad it helped you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ngRoute in your project you can put the below code in your controller.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event){
    console.log('content loaded!')
  });
```

Otherwise wrap your code inside $timeout,

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
  app.controller('testController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.data= "hello";
    });
  });
```

Comment: where exactly do I have to put the ngRoute code in the controller?