# When is DOM ready following jQuery.after - Plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, plupload

**Short version**

After calling `jQuery.after` to insert HTML, how do I know when the DOM is ready?

**Long version**

I'm getting Plupload dropzones from an ajax call and using jQuery.after to insert them. When I then call `mypluploader.init()` to initialize Plupload, it fails due to the DOM not being ready (apparently). Here's what I'm doing:

1. I load the page
2. User clicks Edit
3. I use ajax to get the Plupload zones and insert the returned HTML with jQuery.after
4. I then call `mypluploader.init()` to initialize Plupload
5. I receive the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Code in summary:

```
$.get('/plupload-zones.html', function(theDropZoneHTML) {
        // theDropZoneHTML: <div id='dropzones'>...</div>
        obj.after(theDropZoneHTML); 
        mypluploader = new plupload.Uploader({..., drop_element: 'dropzones', ...});
        mypluploader.init();
        //Boom! It fails
});
```

If I change step 4 to include a setTimeout for 2 seconds it works fine with no error:

```
$.get('/plupload-zones.html', function(theDropZoneHTML) {
        // theDropZoneHTML: <div id='dropzones'>...</div>
        obj.after(theDropZoneHTML); 
        setTimeout(function() { 
            mypluploader = new plupload.Uploader({..., drop_element: 'dropzones', ...});
            mypluploader.init();
            //Bingo! It works
        }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: is your `$.get` wrapped in a *document.ready* handler? SHould work fine if it is

Comment: Yep, it's wrapped in document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, the delay was from an Angular repeater which is also on the page. Waiting for the Angular repeat to finish solved the problem: [ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event)