# ng-repeat sorting arrow not working in javascript datatables

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, datatables, angular-directive

I'm very new to AngularJs and datatables.
I have a requirement to populate the data in table rows using ng-repeat.
Iam able to populate the rows and enabling the sorting for the first time.
When i click on the arrows to sort ascend or descend the row data wiping off.

Here is my table data

```
<table datatable="ng" id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0"    width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col1">Campaign Name</th>
                        <th class="col4">Description</th>
                        <th class="col5">Activate/Deactivate</th>
                        <th class="col5">edit</th>
                        <!-- <th class="col5">status</th> -->
                        <!-- <th class="col5">Details</th> -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    <tr ng-repeat="campaign in campaignListData">
                             <td>{{campaign.campaignObject.campaignName}}</td>
                             <td>{{campaign.campaignObject.campaignMessage}}</td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="pay-amount pending" style="margin-top:-10px;margin-right:17px;width:128px;height:34px"
                            value = "{{ campaign.campaignObject.label }}" title="ACTIVATE" ng-click="updateCampaignStatus(campaign.campaignObject.id)">
                                <span style="margin-left:-10px;margin-right:17px;width:128px;height:34px">{{ campaign.campaignObject.label }}</span>
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="<c:url value="${contextPath}/merchant/manageCampaign/editCampaignConfiguration"/>?campaignId={{ campaign.campaignObject.id }}">
                                <img class="tableImage" style="margin-left:-8px;margin-top:-10px;" src="<c:url value="/resources/images/setting.png" />" ></a>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Here is my sorting javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#noCampaignData").hide();
        //$("#example_paginate").hide();
        var rowCount = $("#example tr").length;
        console.log("Row count value is"+rowCount);
        if (rowCount >= 0) {
            console.log("Entered into Sorting");
            $("#example").dataTable({
                "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
                "order" : [ [ 2, "desc" ] ]
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting rowcount for tr is 1

I have the js file included at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/CampaignListController.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />"></script>
```

When Im loading data its fine loading with ng-repeat. But when i click on header to sort ascending or descending, rows are wiped off.

Please advise me where i'm doing wrong?
I'm unable to sort the data ascending, descending and pagination is not at all working.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No offense, but this is a typical mix-up of jQuery and Angular thinking, or a lack of understanding how Angular works. Here an attempt to wrap some jQuery logic into the [**angular digest loop**](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/). Read a great answer to the question [**“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1407478)

You cannot ever combine `$(document).ready(function() {` and Angular. In fact, you can be very sure that your `ready()` is executed long before Angular has finished its `ng-repeat` business.  And thats why you always get 1 for the row count (the header) and why the rows are dissappearing when you click on the headers. At the time you get row count there is not inserted any rows, and at the time you instantiate the `dataTable()`, no rows have been inserted.

You can use `$timeout` to force delay of the code, or force it into the next digest loop :

```
$scope.initDataTable = function() {
   $timeout(function() {
      $("#noCampaignData").hide();
      //$("#example_paginate").hide();
      var rowCount = $("#example tr").length;
      console.log("Row count value is"+rowCount);
      if (rowCount >= 0) {
         console.log("Entered into Sorting");
         $("#example").dataTable({
            "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
            "order" : [ [ 2, "desc" ] ]
         });
      }
   }, 200)
}
```

or create a [**directive**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that instantiates the dataTable once the data is populated by `ng-repeat`, as demonstrated in multiple answers for [**ng-repeat finish event**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13471129/1407478) :

```
.directive('repeatDone', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) { // all are rendered
            scope.$eval(attrs.repeatDone);
        }
    }
})
```

...

```
<tr ng-repeat="campaign in campaignListData" repeat-done="initDataTable">
```

...

```
$scope.initDataTable = function() {
      $("#noCampaignData").hide();
      $("#example").dataTable({
         ...
      });
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks... Its Awesome explanation you have given and 90% functionality is working...
I'm able to show the headers, arrows and able to populate data in rows and able to paginate also.
One thing missing is the sorting...
When i click on the arrows its freezing and rows are not sorted either in ascending order or descending order.
Any Suggestions? @davidkonrad

Comment: stay blessed dude.. very nice explanation.

Comment: @davidkonrad can you elaborate how we can use search and sort functionality using directive? because in my case those are also not working

Comment: @NullPointer, yes - use the [angular datatables directives](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) really easy to use and support all functionality, here is an example -> http://plnkr.co/edit/nBtzURQxSgKIqFvGMkWC?p=preview In fact I do not think there is so much choice if you really want to use dataTables features, you can have dataTable to work as shown above, but going further you will eventually experience real headaches.

Comment: I tried that too. but it gives me error with 'datatables.directive', that it is missing or either i misspelled the spellings

Comment: hey @NullPointer, you need to include `datatables` in your module and include `DTOptionsBuilder` / `DTColumnBuilder` in the controller. See this plnkr that is using AJAX and try insert your own code  -> http://plnkr.co/edit/o0Ig866BI3cYWAltNoFA?p=preview

Comment: yes i did exactly same but it continuously giving error

Comment: @NullPointer - Fork the plunkr and let me see your code that is not working.

Comment: finally it worked out. Issue was in js file.. thankyou

Answer (score 7):

The example below uses AngularJs and Datatable. The filtering, pagination and sorting are working good.

Download [angular-datatable](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/archive/master.zip) and put *angular-datatables.min.js* file in your project as I do in the line `<script src="angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>`

Hope this can help you.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="AngularWayApp" ng-controller="AngularWayCtrl">
            <table datatable="ng" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="name in names" ng-click="testingClick(name)">
                        <td>{{name.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{name.City}}</td>
                        <td>{{name.Country}}</td>
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <script>
                var app = angular.module('AngularWayApp', ['datatables']);

                app.controller('AngularWayCtrl', function($scope, $http)
                {
                    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php").success(function (response)
                    {
                        $scope.names = response.records;
                    });

                    $scope.testingClick = function(name)
                    {
                        console.log(name);
                    };
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, all I needed was this ==> datatable="ng"

Comment: nice one. its helped me a lot.