# DataTable Bootstrap is not working with AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables

I'm trying to use DataTable Bootstrap with AngularJs, but DataTable works like there is no data in the table. In the code below, I've got two tables. The first one uses AngularJs and the second is only plain HTML.

What do I need to do to make the first table work like the second?

Thanks, People!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

<body>
 <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
     <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
     <td>{{x.Country}}</td>>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

  <br />
  <br />

  <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Rendering engine</th>
     <th>Browser</th>
     <th>Platform(s)</th>
     <th>Engine version</th>
     <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
     <td>Win 95+</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
     <td>Win 95+</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 5.5</td>
     <td>Win 95+</td>
     <td>5.5</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 6</td>
     <td>Win 98+</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
     <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
     <td>7</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Trident</td>
     <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
     <td>Win XP</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
     <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>1.7</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
     <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
     <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
     <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
     <td>1.9</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Camino 1.0</td>
     <td>OSX.2+</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Camino 1.5</td>
     <td>OSX.3+</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
     <td>1.7</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
     <td>Win 98SE+</td>
     <td>1.7</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
     <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.1</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.2</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.3</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.4</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.5</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.6</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
     <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.7</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
     <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
     <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gecko</td>
     <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
     <td>Gnome</td>
     <td>1.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Webkit</td>
     <td>Safari 1.2</td>
     <td>OSX.3</td>
     <td>125.5</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Webkit</td>
     <td>Safari 1.3</td>
     <td>OSX.3</td>
     <td>312.8</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Webkit</td>
     <td>Safari 2.0</td>
     <td>OSX.4+</td>
     <td>419.3</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Webkit</td>
     <td>Safari 3.0</td>
     <td>OSX.4+</td>
     <td>522.1</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Webkit</td>
     <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
     <td>OSX.4+</td>
     <td>420</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Webkit</td>
     <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
     <td>iPod</td>
     <td>420.1</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Webkit</td>
     <td>S60</td>
     <td>S60</td>
     <td>413</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera 7.0</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera 7.5</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera 8.0</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera 8.5</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera 9.0</td>
     <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera 9.2</td>
     <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera 9.5</td>
     <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Opera for Wii</td>
     <td>Wii</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Nokia N800</td>
     <td>N800</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Presto</td>
     <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
     <td>Nintendo DS</td>
     <td>8.5</td>
     <td>C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>KHTML</td>
     <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
     <td>KDE 3.1</td>
     <td>3.1</td>
     <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>KHTML</td>
     <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
     <td>KDE 3.3</td>
     <td>3.3</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>KHTML</td>
     <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
     <td>KDE 3.5</td>
     <td>3.5</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Tasman</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
     <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Tasman</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
     <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Tasman</td>
     <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
     <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Misc</td>
     <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
     <td>Embedded devices</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Misc</td>
     <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
     <td>Embedded devices</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Misc</td>
     <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
     <td>Embedded devices</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Misc</td>
     <td>Links</td>
     <td>Text only</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Misc</td>
     <td>Lynx</td>
     <td>Text only</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Misc</td>
     <td>IE Mobile</td>
     <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Misc</td>
     <td>PSP browser</td>
     <td>PSP</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Other browsers</td>
     <td>All others</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>-</td>
     <td>U</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
     <th>Rendering engine</th>
     <th>Browser</th>
     <th>Platform(s)</th>
     <th>Engine version</th>
     <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
   </tfoot>
  </table>
 </div>

 <script>
 var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
 app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http)
 {
     $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php").success(function (response)
     {
   $scope.names = response.records;});
  });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('#example').dataTable();
      $('#example2').dataTable();
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/30940271/1407478

Comment: Thanks, @davidkonrad! using your solution, some functions work nice, but others don't. I'll keep trying other solutions.
=]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem using the code below. The filtering, pagination and sorting are working good.

Download [angular-datatable](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/archive/master.zip) and put *angular-datatables.min.js* file in your project as I did in the line `<script src="angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="AngularWayApp" ng-controller="AngularWayCtrl">
            <table datatable="ng" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="name in names" ng-click="testingClick(name)">
                        <td>{{name.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{name.City}}</td>
                        <td>{{name.Country}}</td>
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <script>
                var app = angular.module('AngularWayApp', ['datatables']);

                app.controller('AngularWayCtrl', function($scope, $http)
                {
                    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers_mysql.php").success(function (response)
                    {
                        $scope.names = response.records;
                    });

                    $scope.testingClick = function(name)
                    {
                        console.log(name);
                    };
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```