# Why jquery datatable gives me error once every 3-4 times page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-services, datatables

Why am I getting following error every third or fourth time when I refreshes the page:

> DataTables warning: table id=tbl - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 25. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

I read the link http://datatables.net/tn/4, however I am not sure why it's giving me this error if data available is same everytime page is refreshed. I am binding my datatable using ng property.

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                                       datatable="ng" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

I checked for no of `<th>` and `<td>`.
I am binding my rows using following line

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in entities">
```

Comment: race condition? maybe angular is still trying to populate the table when datatables is trying to parse it

Comment: what is the solution to this?

Comment: See [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30944380/3549014) from @davidkonrad for a solution.