# AngularJS Directive Event Listener Not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in $parent.item.detailedPlan track by $index">
  <ul contenteditable="true" class="plan-actions" data-placeholder="Add Plan ...">
    <li ng-repeat="planItem in value" ng-show="(key+1)==$parent.dayItem.value">
      {{planItem}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and a directive function like so:

```
.directive('planText', function(){
      return {
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/planText.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

          element.find("ul").bind('keydown', function(event){
            console.log("keydown event");
          if (event.keyCode == 8) {
            // console.log("backspace pressed");
            if ($(this).children().length == 1 && $(this).children("li").text().split("").length == 0) {
                console.log("stop li removal");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
          }
        });
        element.find("ul").bind('focus', function(event){
            if ($(this).children().length ==0 ) {
                console.log("insert li");
                $(this).append("<li></li>");
            }
        });
        }
      }
})
```

the data structure it reads from, is an array of arrays.
However neither of the event listener functions fires . Adding a $compile does not help either. Please help !

Comment: Can you please post demo? fiddle/plunkr. Did you check that `element.find("ul")` returns something?

Comment: bit difficult to add the fiddle. but in the link phase, it does find the ul. but the handlers dont fire

Comment: do you enter with breaking point to line `if ($(this).children().length ==0 )`?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [codePen](http://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/zwaYOj)

The problem is when u use `ng-repeat` in directive its happened because link fired when element created but ng-repeats start working after that so u can solve this issue by adding `$timeout` before binding.

this question is duplicate of [AngularJS directive runs before element is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074053/angularjs-directive-runs-before-element-is-fully-loaded)