# Protractor: How to get a sibling element

Tags: javascript, dom, protractor

I have a repeater like this

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-mode="d.checked" name="someName" />
    <span>{{d.name}}</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the input:checkbox for the row where span contains text 'test5' i.e. for which span is bound to d.name == 'test5'

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to select that using either CSS selectors or JavaScript once the repeater is bound? Examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event

Comment: Did you try using the xpath as this - `//input[preceding-sibling::span[contains(.,'test5')]]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved it

```
var allO = element.all(by.repeater('o in Types').column('o.name'));
allO.filter(function(elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === 'test5';
    });
}).then(function(sSpan) {
    var parent = oSpan[0].element(by.xpath('..'));
    parent.element(by.css('input')).click();
    browser.waitForAngular();
});
```