# Automatically select last row in a table and invoke function

Tags: angularjs

In Angular How Do I Automatically select last row in a  table  and invoke function

**html**

```
ng-repeat="order in orders | filter: prop.value |orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | limitTo:-3" ng-click="selectOrder(order); setSelected()" class={{selected}}
```

**controller**

```
$scope.setSelected = function() {
    console.log("show", arguments, this);
    if ($scope.lastSelected) {
        $scope.lastSelected.selected = '';
     }
     this.selected = 'selected';
     $scope.lastSelected = this;
}

$scope.selectOrder = function (order) {
    $scope.selectedOrder = order;
};
```

This html returns a list of three orders in a list 
when I click on a row in the list it displays an additional table with the items in an order perfectly

Without clicking on an order no additional table is displayed which is undesirable

Objective:  I want it to automatically select and click the last row so  additional items in an order is always displayed  on screen

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the selectOrder() and setSelected() functions?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a callBack when the last row is generated, and include there the call to your function. There are lots of examples that you can find in internet (for instance, this one [ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event))

Answer (score 0):

for my example this worked and auto selected and invoked the function

ng-init=" $last && selectOrder(order); setSelected()" class={{selected}}>>

Comment: I think it will always select the last element when the list changes, not only at page load. Is this what you want?