# fire directive after ng-repeat is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am using owl carousel,for which data is coming from a ajax call. after ajax ng-repeat with populated the html content.

So i want to fire the directive which makes the owl carousel, after this all is done. How to do that.

One way i can think of using onFinishedRender directive, but this is not working.

directive :

```
directives.directive('onFinishRender',['$timeout', '$parse', function ($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                    if(!!attr.onFinishRender){
                      $parse(attr.onFinishRender);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

controller:-

```
pastWorkService.getAllPastWork()
    .success(function(data) {

        var len = data.length;
        $scope.pastWorkData1 = data.slice(0, len/2);
        $scope.pastWorkData2 = data.slice(len/2, len - 1);
        $scope.owlCarouselPastWork1 = function(){
            $('.owl-carousel2').owlCarousel({
                items: 4,
                loop:true,
                slideSpeed : 1000,
                autoPlay: 3000,
                itemsDesktop: [1199, 4],
                itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 3],
                itemsTablet: [768, 3],
                itemsTabletSmall: false,
                itemsMobile: [479, 1],
                navigation: false
            });
        };
        $scope.owlCarouselPastWork = function(){
            $('.owl-carousel1').owlCarousel({
                items: 4,
                loop:true,
                slideSpeed : 1000,
                autoPlay: 3000,
                itemsDesktop: [1199, 4],
                itemsDesktopSmall: [980, 3],
                itemsTablet: [768, 3],
                itemsTabletSmall: false,
                itemsMobile: [479, 1],
                navigation: false
            });
        };
    });
```

html:-

```
<div class="owl-carousel1" role="listbox" >
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="p in pastWorkData1" on-finish-render="owlCarouselPastWork1()">
        <img src="{{p.mainImage}}" alt="completed-projects" />
        <div class="panel-footer">{{p.apartmentName}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- second row goes here as owl carousel can contain 1 row -->
<div class="owl-carousel2" role="listbox" >
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="p in pastWorkData2" on-finish-render="owlCarouselPastWork1()">
        <img src="{{p.mainImage}}" alt="completed-projects" />
        <div class="panel-footer">{{p.apartmentName}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13472605/548997).

Comment: @Lex Yeah, I got your solution, but isn't mine almost same as yours, but still not working. Can you help me in finding out issue here

Answer (score 0):

Since you simply want to call a function after the last repeated item is rendered, here is one approach you could use:

**html**

```
<div class="owl-carousel1" role="listbox" >
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="p in pastWorkData1">
        <img src="{{p.mainImage}}" alt="completed-projects" />
        <div class="panel-footer">{{p.apartmentName}}</div>
        <span ng-if="$last" on-finish-render function-to-call="owlCarouselPastWork()"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- second row goes here as owl carousel can contain 1 row -->
<div class="owl-carousel2" role="listbox" >
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="p in pastWorkData2">
        <img src="{{p.mainImage}}" alt="completed-projects" />
        <div class="panel-footer">{{p.apartmentName}}</div>
        <span ng-if="$last" on-finish-render function-to-call="owlCarouselPastWork1()"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**directive**

```
.directive('onFinishRender', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            functionToCall: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.functionToCall();
            });
        }
    }
})
```

[Here is an extremely simple and contrived example](https://jsfiddle.net/q888buzb/) to illustrate this idea. You could probably even rework this to have the function in the directive and you would simply pass the class identifier you want to call it on.