# Directive not init properly with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

## The Problem

The directive is not initializing properly when the child directive is have a ng-repeat.

Go to the plunker and check the console. The working one have the outer - link at the end of the console, the not working one have the outer - link function init with the controller.

## The working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kHQZ3LZgLcgp0jFWRwEu?p=info) without ng-repeat

```
<div outer-directive>
    <div inner-directive>

    </div>
</div>
```

#### Console

```
outer - controller
inner - controller
inner - Link
outer - Link
```

## The not working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Y8QEitdLbMGMv8dNEG7?p=preview) with ng-repeat

```
<div outer-directive>
  <div inner-directive ng-repeat="value in [1]">

  </div>
</div>
```

#### Console

```
outer - controller
outer - Link
inner - controller
inner - Link
```

Comment: inner directive DOM get rendered later because of `ng-repeat`..that why you are not getting the expected call stack in `console.log`, you need to wait till last digest cycle complete in inner directive(refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13472605/2435473))..

Comment: But then how to init parent link function after child finish ng-repeat (The child directive need's parent directive's controller).