# Using jquery with dynamically created elements from angular doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Im trying to use jquery to manipulate elements created by angular, but I am not able to get it to work. I was wondering if anyone could help me out. Thanks

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="patients">
    <tbody ng-repeat="patient in patients">
        <tr>
            <td>{{patient.name}}</td>
            <td>{{patient.number}}</td>
            <td>{{patient.date}}</td>
            <td id="item-{{$index}}">{{patient.reminded}}</td>
            <div class="sendreminder">
                <td>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-sm sendreminder" style=" background-color: #00e699; border-color:#00e699; " ng-click="post($index) " "$parent.selected = $index" id="button-{{$index}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Request Payment
                    </a>
                </td>
            </div>
            <td>
                <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:inherit; scale: 4" class="pe-7s-info">
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery

```
$(function() {
$('.patients').on('click', ".sendreminder",function(e){
         alert('worked');
    });

});
```

Comment: how does your rendered html looks like? because i can see couple issues with the markup you are using... `tbody` should go inside a `table` tag, `tr` can only have children of type `td` or `th`, not a `div`

Comment: is there a reason for using `Jquery` it would be much easier if you just use `Angular`

Comment: I dont know angularJS too well. I just started learning it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-repeat recreates DOM everytime it detects changes(and hence, all the attached events will be gone). So to reattach the events after ng-repeat finishes, you can do

```
<tbody ng-repeat="patient in patients" ng-init="$last && ngRepeatFinish()">
```

`$last` will be set to true if its the last item for `ng-repeat`

and in you controller, create `ngRepeatFinish()` function

```
$scope.ngRepeatFinish = function(){
    $('.sendreminder').click(function(e){
         alert('worked');
    });
}
```

you can also make custom directives for this which is better than this, but this will suffice for a quick solution.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event) for a solution with custom directives

Answer (score 1):

You should call that code immediately after you dynamically create the new element since that code sets the handler for the **actual elements** (when you call the function) that have class **.patients**, not the new ones...

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you to use `Angular` instead of `Jquery`

added both methods below

```js
//using Jquery
$('.patients').on('click', ".sendreminder", function(e) {
  alert('from JQuery');
});

function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.patients = [{
    name: 'one',
    number: 1,
    date: '2016-08-16',
    reminded: true
  }, {
    name: 'two',
    number: 2,
    date: '2016-08-16',
    reminded: true
  }, {
    name: 'three',
    number: 3,
    date: '2016-08-16',
    reminded: false
  }];
  //using angular
  $scope.post = function(i) {
    alert('from Angular');
    var selectedPatient = $scope.patients[i];
    console.log(selectedPatient);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div class="patients" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Reminded</th>
          <th>Request</th>
          <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="patient in patients">
          <td>{{patient.name}}</td>
          <td>{{patient.number}}</td>
          <td>{{patient.date}}</td>
          <td id="item-{{$index}}">{{patient.reminded}}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-sm sendreminder" style="background-color: #00e699; border-color:#00e699;" ng-click="post($index)" id="button-{{$index}}">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Request Payment
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; color:inherit; scale: 4" class="pe-7s-info">test
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```