# angular directory slick execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm using the following plugin: http://vasyabigi.github.io/angular-slick/

I'm also using ng-repeat, so I'm experiencing that it's executing before the ng-repeat is done.

Is there any way to fix that?

```
<slick><div ng-repeat="carfactory in vm.carfactory">
        <h4> {{ carfactory.name }}</h4>
        <p>
            <img src="/biler/1.png" style="float: left; padding: 15px; max-width: 100px; height: auto; margin-bottom: 26px;">
        </p>

        <p><b>Pris:</b> {{ carfactory.price | currency }} kroner</p>
        <p><b>Eier:</b> <a href="/">{{ carfactory.ownerid }}</a></p>

        <p>
            <b>Beskyttelse:</b> {{ carfactory.protection }}</p><p><b>Antall igjen:</b> <span id="antall_1">{{ carfactory.amount }}</span>
        </p>

        <p class="hotel-out">
            <input ng-show="carfactory.amount > 0" class="btn btn-block" ng-click="vm.purchasecar(carfactory)" type="submit"value="Kjøp bil!">
            <p class="hotel-in alert alert-warning" ng-show="carfactory.amount <= 0">Gå ut av hotell for å kjøpe en bil.</p>
        </p>
</div></slick>
```

That doesn't work, but if I remove the repeater and copy+paste the code two times it works.

Any idea how to make the ng-repeat work, or how I can get the slicker plugin to wait until it is finished loading?

edit:

if i perform `<slick init-onload="true" data="vm.carfactory"` then i get the following error:

```
slider.unslick is not a function
```

edit: my controller is using     angular.module('garage',['slick'])

Comment: Have you tried to specify <slick init-onload=true data="vm.carfactory"> ?

Comment: that wouldnt make any difference = @KostyaShkryob

Comment: is it possible to add your all code somewhere and give link here so that we can debug?

Comment: @RuhulAmin i tried to add it on jsfiddle, but it was too complicated to get slick to work there.

Comment: Then, I recommend to put in gist /git.

Comment: re: `slider.unslick is not a function` make sure the actual Slick library is on the page: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/ You need both `Slick` and `angular-slick` on the page.

Comment: Are you sure @Sly_cardinal  ?

Comment: @Sly_cardinal still wouldnt work

Comment: @maria Looks like this is an issue with angular-slick library itself. By looking at two two issues they have suggest some solution which works with ng-repeat. I would suggest you to look at these two issue and try. https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/issues/2

Comment: Look at the last comment in the discussion. that will definietly help you. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg will look at it. but then i also need to fix the  slider.unslick is not a function.

Comment: that wouldnt be needed. check this plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/eGNCFG1yASdvOQx8lBel?p=preview

Comment: hmm @DeendayalGarg works now. but if i click my button inside of the slick, it gives me the unslic is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that slick is called before the items in `ng-repeat` are rendered. You can try (re)executing the `slick()` function when the `ng-repeat` finishes rendering using the following code sample:

```
<div ng-repeat="carfactory in vm.carfactory" ng-init="$last && reloadSlick()">
```

[`$last`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) variable ensures that the function is called only for the last item (one time).

Just as a safety measure you can wrap the code in `reloadSlick()` with `setTimeout()` so its execution waits for the next event loop.

```
$scope.reloadSlick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {... code here ...})
}
```

More references about `ng-repeat` rendering callback:

- [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)
- [ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event)