# How to wait until ng-repeat completes looping?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've an example to get json from server and append it to a list.

Script:

```
$http.get('/data/json/cities.json').then(function (res) {
    if (res.status === 200) {
        $scope.cities = res.data;
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<li ng-repeat="(id, name) in cities" id="{{id}}">
    <a href="#" ng-bind="name"></a>
</li>
```

The code where I'm stuck:

```
if (res.status === 200) {
    $scope.cities = res.data;

    // from here
    console.log($('li#NY').length); // 0

    // waiting 1 second and try again
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($('li#NY').length); // 1
    }, 1000);
}
```

The json object contains the key `NY` but I can only assign to the object (`li` tag with id `NY`) after 1 second (or longer).

Is there another way to know when an object (`$('li#NY')` in this case) has been created successful without using `setTimeout`?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? it's not clear from the code why you need this information.

Comment: Try use `ng-repeat-end` directive

Comment: @Karim What's unclear? The list contains `$('li#NY')` object, and the object will be created after I get the json. But when I get the json, I can only assign to the object after 1 second.

Comment: @Hadi `ng-repeat-start` & `ng-repeat-end` will help to place start and end point of directive template(multi template repeat).. I guess OP needs [ng-repeat finish event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13472605/2435473) answer..

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks for the link. I've just checked again. Inside the directive, I have to wait 1 second at least to check length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a directive, follow code below.

```
var module = angular.module('app', [])
        .directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                if (scope.$last === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And then in your controller, you can catch it with $on:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    //you also get the actual event object
    //do stuff, execute functions -- whatever...
    console.log($('li#NY').length); // 1
});
```

With html that looks something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="(id, name) in cities" id="{{id}}" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
    <a href="#" ng-bind="name"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! Can you explain me why do I need `$timeout` there?

Comment: $timeout makes sure it's executed when the ng-repeated elements have REALLY finished rendering (because the $timeout will execute at the end of the current digest cycle -- and it will also call $apply internally, unlike setTimeout). So after the ng-repeat has finished, we use $emit to emit an event to outer scopes (sibling and parent scopes).