# AngularJS: Execute function after rendering using 4 nested $timeout calls

Tags: angularjs

I have nested `ng-repeat` constructions inside my directive like this:

```
<calendar>
    <div class="calendar-row" ng-repeat="calendarRow in calendarRows">
       <calendar-day ng-repeat="calendarDay in calendarRow.days" />
    </div>
</calendar>
```

I need to execute a function after everything will be rendered.
I will achieve this if I wrap my function is inside in 4 nested `$timeout` calls:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $timeout(function() {
                myFunc();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

It looks for me like a hack. Is it possible to reduce `$timeout` calls? I don't understand why 4 calls are needed in my case.
Or is it more elegant way to implement it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event

Comment: Also, wrapping your function in 4 $timeout calls is never the right answer

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by waiting until the ng-repeat has finished rendering?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire, I know that 4 $timeout nested calls isn't a right answer, that's why I posted my question here, otherwise I wouldn't care.
After rendering I have to check if scrolls are visible and set height of rows with class "calendar-row" to another column with rows which one is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be this:

```
<calendar>
    <div class="calendar-row" ng-repeat="calendarRow in calendarRows">
       <calendar-day ng-init="$last && myFunc()" ng-repeat="calendarDay in calendarRow.days" />
    </div>
</calendar>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have already tried this solution and it didn't help. I used `ng-init="$last && $parent.$last && myFunc()"` but still I had to use `$timeout` inside `myFunc()` because `calendar-day` directives weren't fully rendered.