# ng-repeat items not available in post-link function of parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to bind event listeners on `ng-repeat` items from within `post-link` function of "hosting" directive. But during `post-link` call `ng-repeat` items are not rendered yet (please see console log in plunker).

After reading article on directive life cycle (https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/angular-js-demystifying-directives) I got an impression, that in `post-link` all `HTML` should be already available and ready for adding event listeners.

Is [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) somehow different?

Code:

```
angular
  .module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', 
    function() { 
      return {
          scope: { items: '=' },
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
          link: function (scope, element) {
              console.log(element.html());
              var anchors = element.find('a');
              console.log(anchors); 
              anchors.on('focus', function() {
                  console.log('I have focus');
              });
          }
      };
    }
  );
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a href="javascript:;">{{item}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Plunker: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/99qi4eliISMeEWD2?preview

Comment: There are some cases that dom is not ready in link func. You will need to use '$timeout' to ensure that

Comment: Thanks Bill, for your suggestion. I've already found out it will work with $timeout, however I wonder, what are cases, when DOM is not available in link and also why. Using $timeout feels a bit hacky to me, although it's definitely quick solution.

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471129/ng-repeat-finish-event

Comment: Thanks Allabakash, I went through answers and found "workarounds". Although I would like to learn why is `ng-repeat` special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) somehow different?*

The `ng-repeat` adds and destroys DOM based on data. The `.find` operation does not find the elements because they have not been yet added to the DOM.

Add the event handler in a directive which is invoked when the framework adds the element to the DOM:

```
app.directive("myFocus", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem attrs) {
        elem.on('focus', function() {
            console.log('I have focus');
       });
    }
})
```

## Usage

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a my-focus href="javascript:;">{{item}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `myFocus` directive will add the event handler when the `ng-repeat` directive add the element to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a follow up question. When is DOM pre item added to the page? Is it happening outside directive life cycle functions (compile, controller, pre-link, post-link)? I dodn't find any info on `ng-repeat` docs.